# Why can't I use command prefixes?

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

Every I try to use the `commands.Bot(command_prefix='')`, the program reads it as an error. For example, with the code below, it comes out with

> *Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "-ping" is not
> found Ignoring exception in command None:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not
> found*

and is repeated a few times before what i wanted the bot to say (Pong!), is sent 2 or more times in the server...

\I think it might be looping? I'm not sure, but I got it to work once, but the longer I waited, every time used the command it sent more responses? -it sent 16 'Pong's last time I tried... Is there anything I can do about this?\

How can i fix this?

```
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready for use...")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from you prefix, you just forgot parentheses after your `client.command` decorator:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready for use...")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

The `client.event` decorator doesn't have any arguments so you don't need parentheses  but `client.command()` can have arguments like `name=`, `brief=`, `description=`, `aliases`, ... so you need parentheses. ^^

Comment: I think it might be looping? I'm not sure, but I got it to work once, but the longer I waited, every time used the command it sent more responses? -it sent 16 'Pong!'s last time I tried... Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: It shouldn't do this, could you give me a link to your full code ?

Comment: That was just me trying out .command() my real code's pretty long, but the same issue occurs. (I sorted a bunch of quotes based on their mood(?) and the commands should give me a random quote depending on the mood i chose - if that makes sense?)

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/gazalobiye.sql